# MIME type to use when attaching HTML webpage to an email

Tags: c#, html, email, mime-types

Keeping an HTML webpage's contents in a string variable.

I need to attach the webpage to an email, and send it 
(so the webpage is an attachment, not part of the main email).

```
string htmlWebpage = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html><body> Attached Page </body></html>";

string mimeType = "???";

var att = System.Net.Mail.Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(htmlWebpage, mimeType);
```

What is the correct MIME type to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct mime type would be `text/html`.